# Python Dash plotly update table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, callback, plotly-dash

I have a DataFrame in pandas called interesttable, which is getting updated with time (seconds). I am using Dash plotly to display the dataframe. Although i successfully display the dataframe in Dash, I cannot update the Dash with the new rows added in the dataframe. I try the following but it doesn't work. Thank you for your feedback!

```
def generate_table():
    return html.Table(
    # Header
    [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in interesttable.columns])] +

    # Body
    [html.Tr([html.Td(interesttable.iloc[i][col]) for col in interesttable.columns])
    for i in range(min(len(interesttable), 50))]

    )


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[

html.H1(children='Interest Table'),
dcc.Interval(id='generate_table()',interval=1*1000),

generate_table()

])

app.callback(Output('generate_table()','children'), [Input('interesttable', 'n_intervals')])


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Unfortunatelly the error I receive is:

```
 Here is a list of the available properties in "generate_table()":
 ['id','interval','disabled','n_intervals','max_intervals']
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't app.callback supposed to be a decorator?

Try:

`@app.callback(Output('generate_table()','children'), [Input('interesttable', 'n_intervals')])`

I don't see also n_intervals declared.

You should add it:

`app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Interest Table'),
dcc.Interval(id='generate_table()',interval=1000,n_intervals=0 ),generate_table()])`

Comment: That makes sense to do it like this. Without the dcc.Interval, the generate_table() is only called once during application startup